# Intellij with maven seems to detect my dependency but then says not found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij with Maven. I created a java program with an API interface. When I add it to maven, it seems to work because it even recommends me the Java API classes, but when I try to compile it, it says my package doesn't exists.

> package htt.layeredstructures does not exist

[Intellij recommends me using the class I imported from my .jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onnTL.png)

Am I missing something?

The process I did was the following one:

1. File
2. Project Structure
3. Modules
4. Dependencies
5. add
6. JARs or directories
7. Clicked the jar file and ok.

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nU1e.png)

I also added it to my pom.xml like this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>htt</groupId>
            <artifactId>LayeredStructures</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And it matches with the pom.xml of the provider program (the API one)

```
    <groupId>htt</groupId>
    <artifactId>LayeredStructures</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Comment: You don't need to manually add dependencies to the IDEA project structure. Just click "Reload all maven projects" when you edit your pom. Have you run `mvn install` on your dependency project, to install that jar in your local maven repository? Incidentally, why are you using `provided` scope?

Comment: I did not run mvn install in my dependency project because I'm programming on windows and using IDEA integrated maven so I don't even have installed maven and don't have a local repository, so I tought I needed to add it to IDEA

Comment: You can run maven targets from IDEA. Run `install` for your dependency. Then IDEA should find it for your other project.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/22300875/12844632 on how to correctly add your own dependency to the Maven based project

Comment: Thanks you very much @tgdavies I didn't know about the IDEA targets. It works correctly!